# mysql date functions

Tags: mysql, sql-date-functions

I have a date field in the database table of this format 2012-02-1.i need to write 3 different queries:

a.) I need to retrieve all fields where date is between today and previous 5 days.
b.) I need to retrieve all fields where date is older than 5 days from today's date.
c.) I need to retrieve all fields where date between '5 days ago' to '30 days ago'

Can I use some inbuilt mysql function.

Manipulating the query below:

```
SELECT fields 
FROM table 
WHERE date >= CURDATE() - 5
```

or something like this

Or using a between clause. I am not getting the syntax correct.

```
SELECT p.status,p.downpayment_date,p.policy_id,i.id,i.policy_type,i.carrier,i.policy_nu‌​mber,i.client_id,c.id,c.client_name FROM pdp_payment AS p,pdp_policy_info AS i,pdp_client_info AS c WHERE p.policy_id=i.id AND i.client_id=c.id AND (((p.status='close pending') OR (p.status='Cancel')) AND (p.downpayment_date BETWEEN ((INTERVAL 5 DAY AND CURDATE()) - (INTERVAL 30 DAY AND CURDATE()))) )
```

Comment: It is not date time data type..it is of type date.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date between today and previous 5 days.

```
SELECT  fields FROM table
WHERE date_field BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 5 DAY AND CURRENT_DATE
```

Date smaller than previous 5 days.

```
SELECT  fields FROM table
WHERE date_field < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 5 DAY
```

Answer (score 0):

For all fields where date is between today and previous 5 days.

```
SELECT  fields
FROM table
WHERE your_date_field_name BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 DAY AND CURDATE()
```

You can work out other problems in a similar way

Comment: Is the above query logically correct. I am getting a syntax error. The one i reposted on the top

Answer (score 0):

`date` is a keyword, so when you use it as a field name it MUST be enclosed in backticks `` ` `` otherwise you will get a parse error.

To get the range you want:

```
WHERE `date` BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -30 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -5 DAY)
```

Comment: yes i got the date part. But i am not able to get the between syntax.
for eg. I want date between '5 days ago' to '30 days ago'